# Easiest way to deploy ASP web app on ubuntu VPS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, deployment, vps

I already deployed a web app on MS Azure, it was almost one click installation.
Is there a similar way to deploy ASP .Net web app on DigitalOcean.com Ubuntu VPS without Docker?

Comment: When you deployed to Azure, were you on a Linux VM, WIndows VM, or other?

If the application targets .NET Core, you can do it directly and easily since .NET Core is cross-platform. I documented one solution to do it here: https://collinmbarrett.com/deploy-dotnet-core-travis-github-linux/

If it's .NET Framework, you'll need to look into something like mono in order to host on linux.
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/

Comment: actually **docker** offer a very fast and pretty simple way to deploy web apps

Answer (score 0):

Actually after few weeks of searching and experimenting, I found that Docker is the easiest way to deploy ASP.Net cross machines and OS. This a github repo I made  for Docker basics:
https://github.com/aladin002dz/docker-basics